# user input in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to save the users answer in a variable, then use that variable in an if statement.  I tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="number" id="x"/>
<button onclick="calc();";>try</button>
<script>
  function calc() {
      var age = document.GetElementById("x").value;

      if (age >= 35) {
        alert("you are old enough");
      } else {
        alert("you are too young");
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: `GetElementById` --> `getElementById`.

Comment: `GetElementById` doesn’t exist. Check your spelling. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: there is a 2nd semicolumn at: `<button onclick="calc();";>` change it to: `<button onclick="calc();">`

Comment: Added a snippet to my answer. If this works for you accept it :D .

Answer (score -1):

You have a minor typo: first character of "getElementById" should be lower case.

You can see errors like this by opening the developer's console and seeing the message:

```
test.html:6 Uncaught TypeError: document.GetElementById is not a function
    at calc (test.html:6)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (test.html:2)
```

Comment: Could I get a hint as to why this answer was down voted?

Answer (score -1):

Your `getElementById` is capitalized when it shouldn't be.

```
  <input type="number" id="x"/>
 <button onclick="calc();">try</button>
 <script>
 function calc() {
     //Here is your mistake
     var age = document.getElementById("x").value;

  if (age >= 35) {
    alert("you are old enough");
   } else {
    alert("you are too young");
   }
   }
 </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your attempt was almost correct, but `GetElementById` is not a function, it has to be `getElementById` instead.

I also removed the two unnecessary semicolons in your HTML, they are not need here.

```js
 function calc() {
      var age = document.getElementById("x").value;

      if (age >= 35) {
        alert("you are old enough");
      } else {
        alert("you are too young");
      }
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="x"/>
<button onclick="calc()">try</button>
```